Проблема с подключением библиотеки ICU IBM, для работа на c++
Я скачиваю zip файл icu-release75.1 с github, разархивирую его, после чего закидываю его в visual studio, далее запускаю файл alinone.sln. Начинают возникать ошибки
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\data\makedata_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти средства сборки для Visual Studio 2022 (v143). Установите Visual Studio 2022 (v143), чтобы выполнить сборку с использованием средств сборки Visual Studio 2022 (v143).
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\data\makedata_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу ARM64, на которую ссылается файл проекта makedata_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\data\makedata_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу Win32, на которую ссылается файл проекта makedata_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\data\makedata_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу ARM, на которую ссылается файл проекта makedata_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\data\makedata_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу x64, на которую ссылается файл проекта makedata_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\i18n\i18n_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти средства сборки для Visual Studio 2022 (v143). Установите Visual Studio 2022 (v143), чтобы выполнить сборку с использованием средств сборки Visual Studio 2022 (v143).
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\i18n\i18n_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу ARM64, на которую ссылается файл проекта i18n_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\i18n\i18n_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу Win32, на которую ссылается файл проекта i18n_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\i18n\i18n_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу ARM, на которую ссылается файл проекта i18n_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\i18n\i18n_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу x64, на которую ссылается файл проекта i18n_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\common\common_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти средства сборки для Visual Studio 2022 (v143). Установите Visual Studio 2022 (v143), чтобы выполнить сборку с использованием средств сборки Visual Studio 2022 (v143).
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\common\common_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу ARM64, на которую ссылается файл проекта common_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\common\common_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу Win32, на которую ссылается файл проекта common_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\common\common_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу ARM, на которую ссылается файл проекта common_uwp.
C:\icu-release-73-2\icu4c\source\common\common_uwp.vcxproj : warning  : Невозможно найти платформу x64, на которую ссылается файл проекта common_uwp.
Пытался установить компоненты через Visual Studio Installer не помогло.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка
